# Using two Keyspan PR-PR03 presentation remotes in same room

Tags: hardware, powerpoint

If we want to have two Keyspan PR PR03 presentation remotes controlling two different computers in the same room, is there a way to assign a unique ID or frequency to each so one remote doesn't control both computers?

Answer (score 1):

### I got this from their tech support (after the event):

Thank you for your recent inquiry. You will need to change the ID on at least one of your remote controls. To do this, please do the following:

1. Connect your receiver to your USB port.
2. Press the CONNECT button the receiver. The receiver's light will turn on.
3. On the remote control, simultaneously press in on the Composite Switch (black 'wheel' on side of remote) AND hold the laser pointer button until the status red light on the remote control blinks slowly. If your USB receiver blinks at the same time, your remote and receiver are paired. Your remote now has a new ID and the receiver is listening to the new ID. Repeat these steps for every remote you have in the same area. You will now be able to use multiple Presentation Remote Pros in the same area without interference.

ADDITIONAL INFO - - - - - - - - - - - Please note that the Remote's ID is lost if your remote's batteries die or if you change a battery.

Thank you for choosing Tripp Lite!

Please send all replies and inquiries to:
TechSupport@TrippLite.com

Tripp Lite
1111 W 35th Street
Chicago, IL  60609

www.TrippLite.com
Phone:  773-869-1233